# How do I turn part of Redux store into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap-table

Okay, here's the pickle that I'm in, one of my actions in `actions/index.js` is:

```
export function requestPeople() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_PEOPLE,
    })

  const persistedState = loadState() // just loading from localStorage for now
  console.log(persistedState)


  //Object.keys(persistedState).forEach(function(i) {
  //var attribute = i.getAttribute('id')

      //console.log('test', i,': ', persistedState[i])
      //myArr.push(persistedState[i])

    //})
    //console.log(myArr)
  //dispatch(receivePeople(persistedState)) // I'm stuck here
 }
}
```

and when I `console.log(persistedState)` from above in the Chrome console I get my `people` state exactly like this.

```
Object {people: Object}
```

Then when I drill down into `people: Object` above, I get them like this:

```
abc123: Object
abc124: Object
abc125: Object
```

and when I drill down into each one of these puppies (by clicking on the little triangle in Chrome console) I get each like this:

```
abc123: Object
  firstName: 'Gus'
  id: 'abc123'
  lastName: 'McCrae'

// when I drill down into the second one I get
abc124: Object
  firstName: 'Woodrow'
  id: 'abc124'
  lastName: 'Call'
```

Now, here's where I'm stuck.

The table I'm using is Allen Fang's react-bootstrap-table which only accepts array's, and it get's called like this `<BootstrapTable data={people} />` so my above data needs to be converted to an array like this:

```
const people = [{
  id: abc123,
  firstName: 'Gus',
  lastName: 'McCrae'
}, {
  id: abc124,
  firstName: 'Woodrow',
  lastName: 'Call'
}, {
  ...
}]

// and eventually I'll call <BootstrapTable data={people} />
```

My question specifically is how do I convert my `people` state shown above into this necessary array?  In my `action/index.js` file I've tried: `Object.keys(everything!!!)`

And lastly, once I have the array, what's the best way to pass that array into `<BootstrapTable data={here} />` using state, a variable, a dispatched action, something I've never heard of yet?

Any help will be very much appreciated!!  FYI, this is my first question in Stack Overflow, feels nostalgic.  I'm a full-time police officer, and trying learn to code on the side.  Thanks again!

UPDATE:

Thanks to a suggestion by Piotr Berebecki, I'm tying it this way:

```
export function requestPeople() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_PEOPLE,
    })

const persistedState = loadState()
console.log('persistedState:', persistedState)

const peopleArr = Object.keys(persistedState.people).map(function(key) {
  return persistedState[key]
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(peopleArr))

//dispatch(receivePeople(persistedState))
  }
}
```

and getting [null,null,null]

like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

To convert your nested `persistedState.people` object to an array you can first establish an interim array of keys using `Object.keys(persistedState.people)` and then `map()` over the keys to replace each key with an object found in your original nested object - `persistedState.people` - at that key. You can assign the resultant array to a variable which you can then pass to the `BootstrapTable`. Check the code below and a demo here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/yaXrVJ

```
const persistedState = { 
  people: { 
    'abc123' : {
      id:'abc123',firstName: 'Gus', lastName: 'McCrae'
    }, 
    'abc124' : {
      id:'abc124',firstName: 'Woodrow', lastName: 'Call'
    }, 
    'abc125' : {
      id:'abc125',firstName: 'Jake', lastName: 'Spoon'
    }
  }
}


const peopleArr = Object.keys(persistedState.people).map(function(key) {
  return persistedState.people[key];
});


console.log(JSON.stringify(peopleArr));
/* 
Logs the following array:
[
 {"id":"abc123","firstName":"Gus","lastName":"McCrae"},
 {"id":"abc124","firstName":"Woodrow","lastName":"Call"},
 {"id":"abc125","firstName":"Jake","lastName":"Spoon"}
]
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I just tried your suggestions.  But I think my peopleObj is set up a little different, I'm getting `[{"abc123":{"id":"abc123","firstName":"Gus","lastName":"McCrae"},"abc124":{"id":"abc124","firstName":"Woodrow","lastName":"Call"},"abc125":{"id":"abc125","firstName":"Jake","lastName":"Spoon"}}]`

Comment: Here's the code from my reducer used to create my peopleObj: `const initialValues = {

  people: {
  'abc123' : {id:'abc123',firstName: 'Gus', lastName: 'McCrae'},
  'abc124' : {id:'abc124',firstName: 'Woodrow', lastName: 'Call'},
  'abc125' : {id:'abc125',firstName: 'Jake', lastName: 'Spoon'} ,
  },

  addingPerson: false,
}`

Comment: I've just updated my code and codepen. Have a look if it solves your question.

Comment: I think this will do the trick, I'll give it a try when I get home from work this evening.  If so, I'll 'accept' and 'upvote' it, if I have the right Stack Overflow privileges.  If I don't have the privileges, I'll upvote it when I do :) THANKS!!

Comment: Oh, so close!  Now i'm getting `[null, null, null]` I'm gonna try to include an image.  Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: OK, I've found it :) You have a mistake in the `map()` function. You have `return persistedState[key]` but it should be `return persistedState.people[key]` I hope it answers your question :)